# Can one say 'play cello a song'?

Tags: word-usage

Below is what I read [in a film comment](https://www.berkshirefinearts.com/11-10-2014_like-sunday-like-rain-by-frank-whaley.htm). The second sentence makes sense to me, but I don't know how to decompose it. There's only one verb, but two objects - both 'cello' and 'his original composition' need to be played.
Is this the case where the verb has double objects? If that's so, then I feel like there should be a preposition before 'cello', just to sound right in my ears. Could someone tell me what grammar is this called?
Thanks.

> Another academic moment conveys him quoting a long passage from Keats. Or playing cello with a quintet his original composition *Like Sunday, Like Rain*.

Comment: Ditransitive ***to play*** only works where the *direct* object is *something which is **produced** by the act of playing* (such as a ***song***), and the *indirect* object is some kind of *beneficiary, recipient* (such as ***the audience***). If you want to refer to the *instrument* (here, a ***cello***), you need to include a preposition (and article). So you might *Play Mary a song **on the** cello,* for example.

Comment: It's called bad grammar or no grammar at all. It might be interpreted to mean: Or playing his original composition, Like Sunday Like Rain, on the cello in a quintet.

Comment: *Play me Moonlight Sonata* is fine, and *Play me piano* is "just about" credible (but *Play piano for me* is better). But ***Play piano Moonlight Sonata*** (which is structurally identical to OP's cited example) is completely unacceptable.

Comment: It's clear what the writer means, but it isn't a well-constructed sentence. _Like Sunday, Like Rain_ appears to be an instrumental theme rather than a song. You could say "playing [the] cello with a quintet in his original composition" or "playing the 'cello part of his original composition... with a quintet".

Comment: Or playing his original composition *Like Sunday, Like Rain* on his cello with a quintet. This is basically, editing.

Comment: It is fairly normal to omit a preceding article when talking about playing an instrument or otherwise taking part in an orchestra, band, etc. 'Early jazz violinists included Eddie South, who played violin with Jimmy Wade's Dixielanders in Chicago' - 'She also sang contralto in a church quartet. '

Comment: He probably plays the cello *in* a quintet. String quintets include a cello. It would be unusual to have a quintet (of *any* kind) accompanying a solo cello.

Comment: In the UK the increased use of the words **original music** has come about because of TV credits. Programme-makers needed, for legal reasons, to make it clear that their composer didn't write Barber's Adagio, or 'Buddy, Can you Spare a Dime', both of which were included in the soundtrack, but he *did* write all the *rest* of the music. "Original music by" was their way of making that clear. No composer speaks of his 'original composition'. So a cellist might play his own composition, but not his original composition.

Answer (score 1):

The English is very poor quality, Rolala. I don't know what "academic moment" means here. "Convey" is the main verb. There is no main verb in the second sentence. So it should probably be all one sentence.

The second 'sentence' certainly needs to be rewritten.

> Or playing **the** cello **in** a quintet **performing** his original
> composition Like Sunday, Like Rain.

More fluently,

> Or as the cellist in a quintet performing his original composition
> Like Sunday, Like Rain.

Films don't "convey" people: they *portray* them or *show* them.

Also, the film can't show him "quoting Keats **or** playing the cello". "*And*" is needed. If I understood 'academic moment' I might be able to help you turn it into one sentence.

If it's his composition we don't need "original", but for emphasis you might say "his *own* composition."

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This part refers to the character's brilliant performance on many subjects in school. 'Academic moment' means when the character answers teachers' questions. But your answer is quite sufficient. Thank you again.